# Javascript - Object Destructuring - strange

Tags: javascript, angular, destructuring

This is with reference to a MEAN project. In Angular, the two models in question are - Service & Client.

```
export class Service {
    _id?: string;
    servName: string;
    servCat: string;
    freq: string;
    fees: number;
    dueDay: number;
    dueMonth: number;
}

// This is same as the model in Node.
export class Client {
    compName: string;
    ....
    ....
    services?: [{
        servId: string,    // type ObjectId in Node, gets populated when data is fetched in Angular
        fees: number
    }];
}

// This model is used to handled the fetched client data which has populated services data
export class ClientWithProfile {
    compName: string;
    ....
    ....
    services?: Service[];
}
```

In Angular, after editing the Services array, when I am trying to save the Client.

```
console.log('client', this.client)  // of Type ClientWithProfile, i.e. with full services array

//Destructuring client object
const { services, ...otherProps } = this.client

console.log('otherProps', otherProps)  // shows Client data without Services Array

// savingClient is of Type Client
this.savingClient = { ...otherProps }

console.log('savingClient', this.savingClient)
 ////?????? shows client data with Services array, with just servId and fees?????
 /// How is that possible???
```

I am unable to understand the below:
After destructuring `this.client` object (which has full services array), I get a constant `otherProps` without full services array.

When I assign that `otherProps` to another object `savingClient`, how come the services array with just ID and fees is included in `savingClient`? The object `savingClient` was never created before this statement in the code.

Can anyone throw some light here?

Comment: Destructing classes is wrong either call them interfaces and use a simple object or use some function to export one object from another... Too much of your code is not clear. How did `savingClient` got to be of type `Client` if it is created from type `ClientWithProfile` without `services` property?

Comment: Probably unrelated but `services?: [{ servId: string, fees: number }]` looks wrong. Did you mean `services?: { servId: string, fees: number }[]`?